# Oracle SQL Check Exists Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, conditional-statements, exists

I have two simple tables in Oracle SQL Developer (Train and Driver) each with a common attribute (driverid). Essentially what i want to do is to not allow any updates on a particular driver tuple in the driver table if their driverid attribute exists in the train table. I have tried to add the following constraint however it throws back an error of 'subquery not allowed here.'

```
alter table driver add constraint drivcheck CHECK 
 (NOT EXISTS(select driverid from train))
```

I did a bit of digging around and the general feeling is that this condition should be checked with a trigger so I have tried to create a trigger to do the job but not having a lot of success. The below trigger is what i have come up with already.

```
create trigger drivcheck4
before update on driver
for each row
begin
declare
cursor dri is
select driverid from train where 'N' IN  
          (select availability 
           from driver 
           inner join train on    driver.driverid=train.driverid
           );
dri2 NUMBER;
begin
open dri;
loop
fetch dri into dri2;
exit when dri%NOTFOUND;
if check (exists (select * from dri2)) THEN
//Throw Error Section
else
//Allow update operation to take place
end if;
end loop;
close dri;
end;
```

I'm aware the trigger may be performing something different other than as described, but this is just the result of me experimenting. My initial description is what i am trying to achieve. If anyone has any thoughts, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What fields are in the driver table?  Do you want to prevent updates on all of them if they are assigned to a train?

Comment: These are the two tables and their attributes.

Comment: create table Driver(DriverID NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, FName VARCHAR(20), LName VARCHAR(20), Address VARCHAR(30), DOB DATE, Tel_Num VARCHAR(11), Availability CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT driverAvail Check (Availability='Y' OR Availability='N'))

Comment: create table Train(TrainID NUMBER(7) PRIMARY KEY, DriverID NUMBER(5), CoDriverID NUMBER(5), RouteID NUMBER(5), FOREIGN KEY (DriverID) REFERENCES Driver(DriverID), FOREIGN KEY (CoDriverID) REFERENCES Driver(DriverID), FOREIGN KEY (RouteID) REFERENCES Route(RouteID))

Comment: If a driverid is present in the train table, then no operations should be allowed on that drivers record in the driver table. If their id does not exist in the train table, then operations on that drivers record should be possible

Comment: i'm guessing that this is relevant for when the user asks "who is/scheduled to be the driver of this train ? ". in this case you have to query both tables any way. right ? so i think that you are better off (if possible) solving this by using NVL in the join (you are already have to make). like `select t.trainid , nvl(t.driverid , d.driverid) as driverid from train t , driver d where t.trainid = d.trainid`. you can make a view out of it. my believe is that _technology serves deign_ and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew,

Is there any error that you are facing? Something along the following lines should work. If you could post some sample data as well, it would be easy to test.

```
    create or replace trigger trg_bu_driver2
    before update on driver
    for each row
    declare
      l_cnt number;
    begin
    select count(*)
    into   l_cnt
    from   train
    where  driver_id = :new.driver_id;
    if (l_cnt > 0) then
       raise_application_error (-20001, 'new driver id exists in train table');
    end if;
    end trg_bu_driver2;
    /
```

testing:

```
    SQL> select * from driver;

     DRIVER_ID COLUMN2
    ---------- --------------------
            10 driver1

    SQL> select * from train;

     DRIVER_ID   TRAIN_ID COLUMN3
    ---------- ---------- --------------------
            20        100 train1
```

- Updating to a driver id that does not exist in train table.

  ```
    1  update driver
    2  set    driver_id = 30
    3* where  driver_id = 10
  SQL> /

  1 row updated.

  No issues.

  SQL> rollback;

  Rollback complete.
  ```

--updating to a driver id that exists in train table, raises an error.

```
    SQL> update driver
      2  set    driver_id = 20
      3  where  driver_id = 10
      4  ;
    update driver
           *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-20001: new driver id exists in train table
    ORA-06512: at "DMART_ETL.TRG_BU_DRIVER2", line 9
    ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DMART_ETL.TRG_BU_DRIVER2'
```

Comment: thanks for that. I've put up the table creation scripts under the comments above. As for sample data an example of the Train table would be (900000, 1, 2, 7, 87.2, 231.2) and the driver table would be (1, John, Doe, Some Address, 14/09/88, 0011223344, N) (2, John, Smith, Some Address, 10/12/85, 0012345667, N), (3, Johnny, Doey, Some Address, 1/1/91, 00145321456, Y).

Comment: Andrew- Made a couple of syntax corrections. The code is working. Make sure you also check if yourr trigger needs to work on inserts or not. Also, you can edit the question to post DDLs and so on, instead of posting in the comments. Good luck!