# IS-A relation when defining tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ddl

I am trying to implement an `IS-A` relationship between tables.
Say I have a `singer` and a `band` which are `artists`

I want every `artist` to have an ID which is inherited by the `band` or `singer`.

In the code I wrote it appears that a `band` and a `singer` may have the same `ID`. How do I prevent that? And is there a better way to implement this? Reading material is most certainly welcome.

```
CREATE TABLE artists
( id number not null primary key
);

CREATE TABLE singers
( id number not null primary key,
  name char(50) not null,
  last_name char(50) not null,
  foreign key(id) references artists(id)
);

CREATE TABLE bands
( id number not null primary key,
  name char(50) not null unique,
  contact char(50) not null,
  participants number not null,
  check (participants > 0),
  foreign key(id) references artists(id)
 );

insert into artists(id) values(1);
insert into singers(id, name, last_name) values(1, 'an', 'Bish');
insert into bands(id, name, contact, participants) values(1,'un','an',2);
```

as you can see I was able to add a band and a singer with the same ID, under the same "parent."

Comment: Have a look at these answers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5501/how-do-i-map-an-is-a-relationship-into-a-database and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961268/oracle-sql-check-exists-constraint